# How can I map jsonb value into a new array in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I'm fairly new to PostgreSQL specially to the whole set of functions it has to manage JSONs. I have this json example where I can grab always one element but, I want to map it to a new array:

```
select '{"a": {"b":{"c": [{"id":"foo"},{"id":"fuu"}]}}}'::json#>'{a,b,c}';

          column
-----------------------------
 [{"id":"foo"},{"id":"fuu"}]
(1 row)
```

What I really want is:

```
 [foo, fuu]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using Postgres 12 or newer you can use a JSON path query:

```
select jsonb_path_query_array(the_column, '$.a.b.c[*].id')
from the_table
```

This assumes that the column is a `jsonb` column (which it should be). If it's not you need to cast it: `the_column::jsonb`